# Correctly updating the same object on create trigger in firebase realtime DB trigger

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase realtime database trigger on a create node. my need is to update a property based on some condition in the create trigger for the same object. The way i am doing currently is below:

```
exports.on_order_received_validate_doodle_cash_order = functions.database.ref("/orders/{id}")
.onCreate((change, context) => {
  console.log("start of on_order_received_deduct_doodle_cash")   
  const orderId = context.params.id
  const order = change.val();

 var db = admin.database();
 const orderRef = db.ref('orders/')
 return orderRef.child(orderId).update({"_verifiedOrder": true}) 
})
```

As you can see i am getting order id from context and then querying object again and updating it. My question is do i need to do this circus or can i just update it without querying again?

Comment: I don't understand.  What is "this circus"?  Where is the "querying again"?  FYI, `val()` is not a method on a [Change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change) object, but it seems you are not using `order` anyway.

Comment: A small note on the logic of your code: making a trigger that only sets a flag to true doesn't add much insight since you will also know on client side whether there was an error creating the data or not. So your `_verifiedOrder` flag only verifies that data was created, which the client already knew because no exception was thrown.

Comment: Dennis i cut the crap out to keep question relevant. I am doing some processing before actually setting it to true.

Comment: Oke, then my answer below should be helpful. Just squeeze in your "crap" ;-) again  before the return statement and all should be fine.

Comment: so basically my code is fine and just use your hints on not logging entering method, change to snapshot etc. correct?

Comment: Yep, that's my take on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it looks good. Just some small feedback to make you feel more confident about being on the right track.

1. Call the parameter `snapshot` instead of `change` because the parameter name `change` only make sense for the `onUpdate` event trigger.
2. You do not need to log that you're entering the function. Because entering and leaving the function is automatically logged by Firebase also.
3. You can remove the `order` variable that is unused.
4. You are actually not "querying" the object again. Making a reference to a node in the database doesn't make any network call itself. Not until you subscribe to receiving data. So doing `orderRef.child(orderId)` is not a query, it's just a database reference.
5. You can use the snapshot's own reference attribute to shorten your code a bit... effectively throwing away almost all code :-)

So your code code look like this instead. It is doing the exact same thing, just shorter. It was also correct from the beginning.

```
exports.on_order_received_validate_doodle_cash_order = functions
    .database
    .ref("/orders/{id}")
    .onCreate((snapshot) => {
        return snapshot.ref.child("_verifiedOrder").set(true);
    });
```

But as mentioned in my comment above, you are effectively just setting a flag that is confirming that data was saved (or rather: confirming that the function was triggered). You might want to add some logic in there to check whether the order can be placed or not and then set the verified flag to true or false depending on that. Because with the logic of the implementation, all orders will have the value `_verifiedOrder` set to `true`, which is a waste of storage in your database.

Comment: Actually as i am not plain setting it true so can u plz help me modify the above code to show would u update the property later rather just in the trigger invoke itself